# Make an IF condition out of result we get from remote server

Tags: shell-script, ssh, awk, ls

I need to check for files availability in remote server, and based on the files availability i need to make an if condition.

I have tried the below commands in a shell script to list the files in the remote directory that are generated today.

```
FILE=`ssh ${USER}@${HOST} '( cd /home/oracle/SABARISH/logs/sftp && ls -l --time-style=+%D | grep $(date +%D) | grep -v '^d' | awk "'{print $NF}'")' `


echo ${FILE}
```

The above command doesn't produce any output. How do I fix it.

Once it produces output how do I make an if statement out of it if file exists?

Comment: what exactly you wanted to do ?

Comment: My local server will generate files daily and it will be moved to a remote server by means of scp script. If someone has stopped my scp script. I should take care of it. Hence I am planning to do SFTP to a remote server by using a script. Before SFTP I need to check whether the files exists in the remote server (just for validation) for the day, if files are there, exit the script. Or else do SFTP.

Comment: so you wanna check for current date's files, if exists then exit or do SFTP right ?

Comment: Yeah @Rahul you are right!

Comment: see my answer, if that helps you

Comment: That helps me. But why can't we do it using `ls` command?

Comment: I see using `find` command to search specific file much easier, that's why I have used `find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment you want to check current date's file in remote directory, you can do that in following manner:

```
FILE=$(ssh -q "$USER"@"$HOST" 'find /home/oracle/SABARISH/logs/sftp -type f -daystart -mtime -1 | wc -l')

if test "$FILE" -eq 0; then
        exit
else
        # do your SFTP stuff here
fi
```

from `man find` :

```
-daystart
    Measure times (for -amin, -atime, -cmin, -ctime, -mmin, and -mtime) from the beginning of today rather than from 24 hours ago. This option only affects tests which appear later on the command line.
```

Comment: `-mtime -1` is listing even files that are created yesterday.  It is listing down 17/06/2016 and 16/06/2016 files.

Comment: @sabarishjackson in that case you can use `-daystart` option.

Comment: @sabarishjackson see my updated answer

Comment: Hey. But that ssh command doesnt exit from the remote server without mannual interup..???

Comment: @sabarishjackson I didn't get you

Comment: `ssh -q "$USER"@"$HOST" 'find /home/oracle/SABARISH/logs/sftp -type f -daystart -mtime -1 | wc -l ` this command doesn't exit from remote sever. It is expecting exit command,.